# ASP quit working today?

Tags: asp-classic

All of a sudden on a working Windows 2003 server - ASP just up and quit serving pages?

I have a simple hello.asp script that reads:
http://www.icontrolwebstudio.com/hello.asp

And when I run it - I get:

```
msxml3.dll error '80072efe'
The connection with the server was terminated abnormally
/LM/W3SVC/7/Root/global.asa, line 63*
```

I also have a test.asp page that just has text in it:

```
Test - Page is running.
```

And I am getting the same error?

Not sure what the deal is, any help would be greatly appreciated?

Chris

Comment: Seems like a network issue .. what's it (MSXML, when presumably all call that is trying to connect remotely) trying to talk to? Is it still alive?

Comment: What is in your global.asa file on line 63. Are you creating a DB connection or something in there?

Comment: WHen I visit http://www.icontrolwebstudio.com/hello.asp I see the text hello and when I visit the page test.asp I see the following text: Test - Page is running.

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem is your antivirus or firewall interfering with the connection or it can also be caused by a name resolution issue like when the host name resolves to 127.0.0.1 (via local) and the web server is bound to the public IP address only.